# mi web inserta datos a una bd cada vez que recargo la pagina

Tags: php

Mi pagina web contiene un formulario para agregar usuarios a una tabla y cada vez que se recarga la pagina inserta automáticamente los últimos datos que había agregado anteriormente a mi base de datos MySQL. Mi pregunta es como puedo solucionar esto.

Este es mi form en el código HTML.

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput" class="form-label">Example label</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control"
      id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input placeholder">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2" class="form-label">Teléfono</label>
    <input type="number" name="telefono" class="form-control" 
      id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input placeholder">
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Este es mi código PHP

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "maxwell230102";
$dbname = "busquedas";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
  die("Error de conexión: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO campos (nombre, telefono) VALUES ('$nombre', '$telefono')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "Datos insertados correctamente en la base de datos";
} else {
  echo "Error al insertar datos: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: por regla general antes de cada insert debes hacer un select para verificar que el dato no exista ya en la base, y también se hace una redireccion despues del insert para otra pagina para evitar esto.

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias formas. Acá algunas de las más básicas.

Veo que tu archivo procesador se llama **search.php**, lo primero que deberías hacer ahí es verificar si ha habido un envío de formulario, esto se puede hacer de manera fácil con

```php
if ($_POST) {
    # code...
}

if ($_GET) {
    # code...
}
```

Otra cosa es lo que te dice John, hay información se debe verificar antes de meterla a la DB, eso lo puedes hacer consultando primero algún dato identificador (DNI, Pasaporte...)

Yo creo que esto lo puedes evitar si dejas como único los campos que en la mayoría de casos son únicos, por ejemplo, usuario, DNI, o para el caso de tu formulario, el teléfono.

Puedes hacer algo tan fácil, como buscar el teléfono de alguien en la DB y si ya existe no hacer nada (o lo que tu quieras). Yo prefiero manejar los campos únicos, pero ojo, que si no lo haces bien y tienes un campo (como el ID) `autoincrement` esos campos pueden verse afectados con un nuevo registro y llenaras la DB de basura.

Comment: Otra forma es enviar desde la parte frontend  todos los datos incluido el uuid. Este lo marcas como uniqu en la BBDD y así, si ya existe, te dará error al insertar si no cambias el uuid

Answer (score 0):

¿Te refieres a que se vuelve a insertar si actualizas el navegador cuando sale el mensaje "*Datos insertados correctamente en la base de datos*"? Hay varias formas de resolver esto, pero una forma simple y funcional desde el backend (usando sesiones):

Creas una variable en el **inicio de sesión** del usuario, por ejemplo:

```php
$_SESSION['insert_time'] = microtime();
```

Ahora en los formularios agregas un `input` así:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="form_time" value="<?php echo microtime();?>">
```

Finalmente en el archivo php donde se hace el insert comparas si el valor que está en `$_POST['form_time']` es diferente de `$_SESSION['insert_time']`, si es así entonces permites el **INSERT** y actualizas la variable de sesión. De lo contrario, significa que el usuario ha refrescado la página y puedes poner un mensaje de que el registro ya fue insertado.

```php
if($_POST['form_time'] != $_SESSION['insert_time']) {
    // rutina de insertar en la BD
    $_SESSION['insert_time'] = $_POST['form_time']; // <-- IMPORTANTE
} else {
    // El regitro ya fue insertado, no insista.
}
```

La variable de sesión, al ser superglobal, la puedes reutilizar en todos los formularios que quieras del proyecto.